# How do I set up a Lightning Node on Mainnet using windows?

Tags: lightning-network

I want to set up a lightning node on windows. I have found [lightning-app](https://github.com/lightninglabs/lightning-app/releases/download/v0.1.4-alpha/Lightning-win32-x64v0.1.4.zip) which seems to work only on testnet. help me finding a good guide to set up a lightning node on windows.

the reason I am insisting in the frustrating windows platform is to make it familiar with other people showing it really works on mainnet and setting it up for non-programmers. but I have found [some guide on medium](https://medium.com/@jadmubaslat/bitcoin-lightning-network-node-easy-setup-tutorial-for-windows-desktop-users-a-how-to-guide-9937b5a8a669) which shows how to set it up on testnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Eclair](https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair).

It has a nice GUI, runs on Windows, and just a few days ago they have announced a new version that officially supports mainnet usage.

It requires a Bitcoin Core node to runs alongside it, and a little configuration.